# Keep last X Commits and History

Tags: git

tl;dr: How do I keep the last X commits and commit history in a Git repo?

My git hosting provider only allows up to 2GB worth of data for the entire git repository (including history). I'm using the repository to commit daily database backups every night. Right now the backup is around 400mb and is overwritten every night. After 40 days it finally reached the 2GB limit (due to the commit history). My temporary solution was to rename the current repo to **DB Backup - 2** and create a new repo, as they don't have a limit on the number of repos you have, just the total size of a single repo. This is fine, but I don't want to have to do this every month or so. I probably really only need 2 weeks worth of backups. If we don't notice bad data within 2 weeks, then that's on us. So what Git commands would I need to use in order to keep the last x commits and wipe the remaining history? I tried the commands from [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1505280) and it works well except that it gets rid of **All** the history.

Comment: Have you considered writing a script which interactively rebases the repository to squash/delete any commits which are greater than X commits old? It would be a bit tricky to script, and git might have better commands to use, but hypothetically it could do this

Comment: I'm open to it, or anything really. I am not experienced with git commands whatsoever and the documentation is vast and confusing to me.

Comment: In all honestly I don't think you should be using git for this. Git is intended to provide a permanent record of a project, save the differences between each version and provide collaboration tools for teams. Deleting commits at the beginning of history is antithetical to the way git is designed, and comes with a lot of pitfalls. There is lots of free DB backup software which would fit your needs much better. Also https://learngitbranching.js.org is a good resource if you want to understand the underpinnings of git, and why this is a bad idea.